# Crop an image (or other objects) too large for a div

Tags: css, image, crop

I have an image in my header that I would like to crop whenever its DIV is narrower than the image itself.

Here's the page when I scale the browser window down: a slider appears and you can see the grey body

[image]

Here's what I would like to happen: for the div to be cut off, and you can't see the rest of the image without scaling the window back.

[image]

It would be ideal if this was the property of the div, rather than the image, so that whatever other object is placed in the div, behaves in the same way.

I'd love to post a more in-depth illustration of the problem, but I've lost my previous account and I don't have the reputation to post the links/images.

I've already tried overflow: hidden and it doesn't do anything for a single object (it hides additional objects though).

**EDIT: Ok, so here's where my mistake was: I typed in overflow: "hide" instead of "hidden", now it works perfectly. Thanks for the answers!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
overflow:hidden;
```

at your container DIV

Answer (score 1):

use overflow hidden like this on the parent element(.slider in your case I guess)

```
.parent{    
overflow-x:hidden
}
```